# Im using jmeter for performance tesing while executing getting error can any one suggust me

Tags: apache, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, manual

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me how to solve?

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Then read [ask] and take a few minutes to add some details to your question, especially an [mcve].

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "HTTP sampler" if your are trying to send some request instead of HTTP Request Default config. There is only config component in your test plan. Include HTTP sampler. In case of any other issue, please post the error details/log.

You can use sample template available for building basic test plan. Also check how to record request using [jmeter.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: Again download the jmeter...You might have some issue with current setup/files